# Saddle point or not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y)=2xy-x^3-y^2$. One of the stationary points is $(0,0)$. At this point, $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}<0$. According to me, this indicates that (0,0) is a saddle point. However, the text I am referring to calls this "neither an extremum nor a saddle point". Am I missing something?

Edit
The plot (from GeoGebra) looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: a saddle point should have positive curvature along one direction and negative curvature along another

Comment: You have to take into account the value $f_{xx}(0,0)=0.$

Comment: @phdmba7of12 So, how do we show in this case that it is (or isn't)? Are there any necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: @user376343: Please elaborate. One of the texts I am following says that if $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}{yx}<0$ then  it is a saddle point. No restrictions are given on $f_{xx}$.

Comment: looks like it's partial derivative along one direction is zero at zerozero

Comment: @phdmba7of12: So other than the determinant of the Hessian, we need to check if $f_{xx}$ or $f_{yy}$ is non-zero and only then conclude if it a saddle?

Answer (score 4):

You're right, and there's a mistake in the example. I'm pretty sure something like $x^3+y^2$ was intended; that's genuinely not a saddle point, despite increasing in some directions and decreasing in others.

This is also dependent on the definition; some sources define a saddle point to be a critical point that's not a maximum or minimum, in which case this situation would be impossible.

Comment: I see. So if we consider the purely geometric meaning of it "looking" like a saddle (max from one side and min from another), then this is not a saddle (as shown in the graph above)?

Comment: @PGupta: It **does** look like a saddle, **near the origin**! You need to zoom in much more in your picture.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the path $y=x$ then $f(x,x)=x^2-x^3$ meaning a local minimum.  If you follow $y=-x$ then $f(x,-x)=-3x^2-x^3$ meaning a local maximum.  These behaviors match $g(x,y)=xy$, an archetypal saddle point at the origin.

Comment: So it is a saddle point, and not what the book says? I must point out here that there are other examples in the book as well where it is claimed that the stationary point is not a saddle or an extremum, but it doesn't look like there would be so many typos in the text.

Comment: I would call it one.  Not sure what the book authors are thinking.

Answer (score 0):

here's what the function looks like (would have posted as a comment but can't)
[image]

Comment: Can we conclude it is not a saddle point without using the 3D graph?

Comment: of course ... i'm always a fan of graphing functions ... by hand if necessary

Comment: Definitely, graphing gives visual clarity. But 3D graphs are difficult to visualise without a computer. I plan to show the graphs to my students in the class, but they won't be able to draw them/visualise during an exam.

Comment: agree with your point ... absolutely

Comment: Then how should they answer the question!?

Answer (score 0):

From graphical [plot](https://www.math3d.org/V8J0bxa3), it appears to be a saddle point having positive and negative curvature along mutually perpendicular directions

[image]

[image]